# how to concatenate each record within one observation in SAS

Tags: sas

I wonder whether it's possible to concatenate each record within one observation with SAS code.
E.g.

Here is the original data set

**1st_name 2nd_name 3rd_name .....last_name**

```
   abc   def      ghi .....     xyz
```

Now I want to add a variable that concatenates all values from 1st_name to last_name--separated by a specific separator, if possible.

**Expected result**

**1st_name 2nd_name 3rd_name .....last_name   all_name**

```
   abc   def      ghi .....     xyz     abcdefg...xyz
```

Of course there is one way

```
data name;
  set name;
  length all_name $ 30;
  all_name=1st_name||2nd_name....||last_name;
run;
```

However, things will get terrible if there are hundreds of variables. So the question has been how to do it automatically, without having to specify variable names, numbers etc.

Looking forward to answers from SAS experts:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code below should work. You'll need to tweak it to your own situation. What it does is creating an array of all character variables. If the name contains the value name it will be concatenated. The catx functions trims the values and uses the first parameter as seperator. Just be aware that the maximum size of a SAS field is 32767 characters, so concatenating hundreds of variables might result in an error.

```
data concatnames (drop=i);
 * maximum field length, will contain concatenated names;
 attrib all length=$32767.;
 * read source dataset;
 set names;
 * create array with with character fields;
 array char_array {*} _character_;
 * loop through array;
 do i = 1 to dim(char_array);
  * if fieldname contains name, then add to all with a dash as seperator;
  if (index(vname(char_array{i}),"name") ne 0) then all = catx("-",all,char_array{i});
 end;
run;
```

Comment: +1 This is a great answer, nice explanation and an elegant, generalisable solution. I like it that you're here, Laurent!

Comment: If you don't need a '-' delimiter between each concatenated value, change the catx("-",all,char_array{i}) for cats(all,char_array{i}).

Comment: Thank you again, Laurent. I agree with Frog since it's really useful,indeed.CHeers!

Answer (score 7):

If the variables to concatenate are in order, your can use the "of" syntax with a variable list (the double dash) to simplify the code.

```
data name;
  length all_name $32767.;
  set name;
  allname=cats(of first_name--last_name);
run;
```

Comment: This may be an old answer, but you just saved me so much time on a related problem that I had to post to say thanks!

Comment: I used this code to concat and works great, but how do you insert a comma between first and last name into this code?

Comment: @SQUISH - The related catx() function allows you to include a separator in the concatenation - but this separator would be added between all elements.  Not sure if this is what you need or not but might be worth checking out.